# Использование UNION в Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine2

Здравствуйте! 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, в проекте используется doctrine 2, есть запрос в бд подготовленный через Doctrine QueryBuilder. К нему нужно добавить 1 строку из другой таблицы. само собой напрашивается использовать UNION, но QueryBuilder не поддерживает его. Можно переписать все используя NativeBuilder, но дальше приложение работает именно с объектом QueryBuilder и переделывать придется очень много. Может кто знает как обойтись малой кровью и добавить строчку, может есть способ скормить QueryBuilder sql запрос? или еще что то?

```
$query->select($selectFields)->from($transactionTableName, 't')->leftJoin('t', 'user', 'u', 'u.id = t.executorId')->join('t', $operationTableName, 'o', 'o.id = t.operationTypeId AND o.isBase = 1');
    if ($relationAdapter instanceof \Payment\Service\Adapter\Credit) {
        $query->leftJoin('t', $relationTableName, 'senderRel', 'senderRel.id = t.senderRelationId')->join('senderRel', 'creditRequest', 'credit', 'credit.id = senderRel.creditId')->join('credit', 'procedureLot', 'lot', 'lot.id = credit.lot_id')->join('lot', 'procedures', 'p', 'p.id = lot.procedureId');
    } else {
        $query->leftJoin('t', 'procedureLot', 'l', 'l.id = t.lotId')->leftJoin('l', 'procedures', 'p', 'p.id = l.procedureId');
    }
    $query->where('t.recipientRelationId = :relation')->orWhere('t.senderRelationId = :relation')->orderBy('t.dateTime', 'DESC')->groupBy('t.id')->setParameter('relation', $relationAdapter->getRelation()->getId());
    $query->addOrderBy('t.id', 'DESC');
```

Comment: В чем проблема сделать два разных запроса?

Comment: @etki результат выводится в одну таблицу приложения

Comment: Ага, а проблема здесь в чем?

Comment: @etki добавил кусок кода в вопрос, может поможете написать еще запрос, так чтобы он ушел и вывелся потом?